# Suitable layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to choose suitable layout for my situation. It will contain three elements: picture, text, button. His task is to be in one line when text is little, and be in two lines if there is big text.

The left side of the picture is tied to the left border of parent. The text on the left is bound to the right edge of the picture, and expands to the right border of parent. The picture is centered vertically relative to the text. RelativeLayout copes with these tasks. But the button has a special behavior.

The button has its right side tied to the right border of parent. But the left side is the trigger: if it reaches the right border of the text, the button goes down below the text, and the layout is now in two rows (visually).

[concept picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbgZB.png)

**Is there such an layout? What would you choose? Thanks for your help.**

P.S. recently I discovered Barrier in ConstraintLayout, perhaps there is a similar trigger, but which pushes the elements when there is not enough space for them... Current code id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:srcCompat="#f00"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text"
            android:textColor="#F00"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```